# Is "template argument deduction for class templates" supposed to deduce empty parameter packs for variadic class templates?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

The *"Template argument deduction for class templates"* proposal *([P0091R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r2.html))* contains the following example:

```
template<class ... Ts> struct X { X(Ts...) };
X x1{1}; // OK X<int>
X x11; // OK X<>
```

*(Apart from the fact that the constructor definition is missing a body)*, the example seems to suggest that a **variadic class template** constructed with zero argument will be deduced with an empty parameter pack.

Unfortunately, the latest version of **g++** does not agree:

```
int main()
{
    X x1{1};
    X x11;
}
```

```
 In function 'int main()':
 error: invalid use of template-name 'X' without an argument list
 X x11;
 ^
 note: class template argument deduction requires an initializer
```

[**example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nMMS06MRgelPhlO1)

---

I could not find explicit wording in the proposal that clarifies this interaction. Is g++ wrong here?

Comment: `X x11{};` works.

Comment: I'd say gcc implementation is in the experimental stage right now. i.e. `vector v{2,3}` works, but `vector v{2,3,4}` yields an error that `'int' is not a class, struct, or union type`.

Comment: @krzaq: it seems that it tries to call [constructor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for that particular case. I wonder if this is actually intended *(i.e. what are the rules for disambiguation in these cases)*. By the way, I am aware that gcc is in the experimental stage - my interest is filing bug reports where appropriate.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo the vector is filled with values 2 and 3, not with 3 and 3. It does call the constructor you mentioned if you initialize it with `vector v(2,3)`

Comment: In retrospect, I think that `vector v{1,2,3}` failing does make sense, as `vector{1,2,3,4}` fails as well. `vector v{{1,2,3}}` compiles as intended.

Comment: Don't you just love the "universal construction" syntax? It's even more confusing than the earlier one...

Comment: @krzaq: ah, I see the inconsistency now - I assumed the binary version  called constructor (2) as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now well-formed after [P0620R0](https://wg21.link/P0620R0) removed the cited restriction right before C++17's publication.

<sub>Previous answer kept for reference:</sub>

---

N4618 [[dcl.type.class.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/dcl.type.class.deduct#1):

> If a placeholder for a deduced class type appears as a
>   *decl-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *simple-declaration*, the *init-declarator* of that declaration shall be of the form
>
> > *declarator-id* *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *initializer*

The initializer is not optional.

Comment: Nice. That's a very handy website!

Comment: @Yakk Yes, although it looks like [they are tweaking the thing](https://twitter.com/AlisdairMered/status/797227816999743490) so maybe I'll have to edit this soon...